# Laravel 4 handle post as get

Tags: forms, post, routes, laravel-4

I'd like to handle POST requests as GET. How can I do that?

In route I have defined

```
Route::post('campaign/update', 'ApiCampaignController@postUpdate');
```

And than, in postUpdate **($id, $value, $field)** I want to use function params **($id, $value, $field)** to retrieve data instead of Request::get.

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you would like to do a Post Redirect Get as described here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get , then you can simply make sure you have a route configured for Post, and then a route configured for Get, and then in your Post function you simply redirect to the Get. Here is an example I used in one of my web applications, where I take a users' report query and redirect it to a get request, allowing them to bookmark a report if they so wish:

```
public function postSearchVendorInvoices()
{
    $startDate = Input::get('start_date') != '' ? Input::get('start_date') : '*';
    $endDate = Input::get('end_date') != '' ? Input::get('end_date') : '*';

    return Redirect::action('BillingController@getVendorBilling', array(Input::get('search_contact'), $startDate, $endDate, Input::get('collected', 0)));
}
```

Comment: No, this is'nt that I want to do.. I want to use method params instead of Input::get() function!

Comment: Oh, in that case you need to a) include the parameters in your form post url, and b) include the parameters in the Route definition.

Comment: You suggest me to use GET instead of POST.